# Android: How to check if an Activity has an options menu?

Tags: android

Given an Activity object, is there a way to determine whether it has an options menu?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a flag in the "onCreateOptionsMenu" method that you could check for to see it had ever been called.

Comment: I think it will always be called in Honeycomb or ICS.

Comment: You're correct.  I just thought it worth mentioning but not worthy of being posted in a separate answer. :)

Comment: Sorry I wasnt paying attention. I though the OP was giving extra info.